# Designing with types and integer constraints in F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

How can I design an integer type in F# that initialize to 0 and have some method that always increase the value monotonically, i.e. first call to the method return 1, second call 2 etc.

Here is OCAML code describing what I would like to achieve in F#

```
module TERM : sig
  type t
  val succ: t -> t
  val init: unit -> t
  val compare: t -> t -> int
end

module Term : TERM = struct
  type t = int
  with compare
  let succ = succ
  let init() = 0
end
```

Comment: If you would like to drop the fancy type work a closure over an int ref would do the job.

Answer (score 4):

you can translate this directly into a type (should be possible in ML too):

```
type Term =
   | Init
   | Succ of Term
```

Of course it might not be the most performant so you probably something like this instead (closer to your version too):

```
module Term =

   type T = private T of int

   let init ()             = T 0
   let succ (T i)          = T (i+1)
   let compare (T a) (T b) = compare a b
```

sadly F# does not have the great modules Ocaml has so I fixed `int` here

### generic version

You can make this a bit more generic if you really want:

```
module Term =

    type T<'a> = 
        private T of 'a with
        override x.ToString () = 
            match x with 
            | (T i) -> i.ToString()


    let inline init ()      = T LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline succ (T i)   = T (i + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne)
    let compare (T a) (T b) = compare a b
    let getValue (T i)      = i
```

but I don't know if you will like the usage/types afterwards:

```
> Term.init () |> Term.succ;;
val it : Term.T<int> = 1

> let (t : Term.T<float>) = Term.init () |> Term.succ;;
val t : Term.T<float> = 1
```

### comparision and stuff

just to be clear: I added the `compare` just to be *in line* with the question. **you don't really need it** as the `type T` will support this by default.

For example just this:

```
module Term =

    type T<'a> = private T of 'a 

    let inline init ()      = T LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let inline succ (T i)   = T (i + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne)
```

will work as expected:

```
> let one = Term.init () |> Term.succ;;
val one : Term.T<int>

> let two = Term.succ one;;
val two : Term.T<int>

> one = Term.succ (Term.init ());;
val it : bool = true

> one < two;;
val it : bool = true

> one >= two;;
val it : bool = false

> compare one two;;
val it : int = -1
```

### if you care for the struct/value type

go with @Vandroiys answer or make this slight adjustment:

```
module Term =

    type [<Struct>] T<'a> internal (a : 'a) = 
        member internal __.value = a

    let inline init ()         = T (LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero)
    let inline succ (i : T<_>) = T (i.value + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and see how the generic version feel like to work with.

Answer (score 3):

A minimal value-type implementation:

```
type [<Struct>] Term private (i : int) =
    member __.Value = i
    member __.Next = Term (i + 1)
    // optional static members
    static member Zero = Term ()
    static member value (t : Term) = t.Value
    static member next  (t : Term) = t.Next
```

- Equality and comparison are supported by default. You need no additional code for that.
- The required default constructor for structs `Term()` will create a zeroed struct, with value `0`.
- This is a value type; its usage causes no additional heap allocations.
- The static member Zero is a standard name used in some library methods' member constraints, such as `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero`. This compatibility doesn't matter much here, but it is a suitable standard name; personally, I'd use either `Zero` or the default constructor in place of `init`.

Usage test:

```
Term.Zero.Next = (Term.Zero |> Term.next) // true
Term.Zero < Term.Zero.Next                // true
```

*Generalization of this approach does not allow the* `Next` *instance member (the static member is fine), since F#'s member constraints are not supported on types. If this is a requirement, I would also consider an* `internal` *constructor, or the approach of [Carsten König's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665799/4191347), which utilizes a singleton DU to allow module-private construction.*

---

*In case someone comes here just looking for a function that returns increasing integers, what Str hinted at in the question's comments is:*

```
/// Returns 1 on first call, otherwise last issued + 1
let intSource =
    let i = ref 0
    fun () -> incr i; i
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, F# doesn't fully support ML-style modules (or functors).  The existing answers cover ways to use idiomatic F# to handle certain cases where your existing module could be used, but are fairly restricted.

A more faithful, but less idiomatic and far more cumbersome, translation might look more like this:

```
type TermRec<'t> = {
    succ: 't -> 't
    init: unit -> 't
    compare: 't -> 't -> int
}

type TermUser<'z> =
    abstract Use : TermRec<'t> -> 'z

type Term =
    abstract Apply : TermUser<'z> -> 'z

let mkTerm r = { new Term with member this.Apply(u) = u.Use r }

let term1 = mkTerm { succ = (fun i -> i + 1); init = (fun() -> 0); compare = compare }

let term2 = mkTerm { succ = (fun i -> not i); init = (fun() -> false); compare = compare }

let user = { 
    new TermUser<_> with 
        member this.Use(t) = 
            t.compare (t.init() |> t.succ |> t.succ) (t.init()) }

let v1 = term1.Apply user
let v2 = term2.Apply user
```

In particular, note that:

1. Terms with different type parameters are fully supported (`int`s, `bool`s, etc.).
2. Terms hide the type parameter of their underlying `TermRec<_>`, and users that would leak values of this type will not compile (although you *could* create a `TermUser` that uses .NET reflection to break the encapsulation at runtime and return e.g. the string name of the type).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to create a function that delivers a new value each time it gets called, the usual solution consists in using a ref for the counter and keeping it private. In OCaml, the code is:

```
let create_counter initial_value =
  let counter = ref initial_value in
  fun () ->
    let result = !counter in
    incr counter;
    result
```

It is used as follows:

```
# let new_id = create_counter 0;;
val new_id : unit -> int = <fun>
# new_id ();;
- : int = 0
# new_id ();;
- : int = 1
# new_id ();;
- : int = 2
# new_id ();;
- : int = 3
```